# Using GetElementByID multiple times, with a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, getelementbyid

im having the issue that i want to use the same GetElementByID multiple times, since i cant set it to a defined value - it needs to be scalable.

Part 1:

```
    <span class="hiddenAV">AV:</span><input type="text" id="AttVector" onfocusout="getBV()">
    <span class="hiddenAC">/AC:</span><input type="text" id="AttComp" onfocusout="getBV()">
    <span class="hiddenPR">/PR:</span><input type="text" id="PRReq" onfocusout="getBV()">
```

Part 2:

```
    AV = document.getElementById("AttVector").value;
    AC = document.getElementById("AttComp").value;
    PR = document.getElementById("PRReq").value;
```

What im trying to do is something like:

```
    for (i=1; i<40; i++) {
      var i = document.getElementById("AttVector" + i)
    }
```

Somehow i cant find a way, to implement this piece of code - or is there any better/easier implementation?

Thanks!

Edit:
The Problem im facing is, that if i get more than just one "AttVector" back, my Code cant assign the second "AttVector". Therefore only the first calculation works, at the moment.

Comment: Providing you really have elements with id of `AttVectorX` (where X is an integer), you should use a different variable name than the loopcounter to store the reference. As it is, the code doesn't do anything with the reference, though. Also, almost always, if you need dynamic ids, you're doing something wrong, and you should rethink the logic.

Comment: You can refer to this article and use event delegation instead https://javascript.info/event-delegation

Comment: The id you call it with is always different so you are not calling it more than you need. However I'd probably consider using classes and `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: @Teemu `(Element)++` results in `NaN` which is never less than 40 so that's definitely a problem

Comment: @Phil Yes, that's why I said they should use a different variable name.

Answer (score 2):

Give all of the relevant `<input>` elements a common class, then it'd be easy to loop through them:

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");

for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  console.log(inputs[i].id);
}
```

```html
<span class="hiddenAV">AV:</span><input type="text" class="myclass" id="AttVector" onfocusout="getBV()">
<span class="hiddenAC">/AC:</span><input type="text" class="myclass" id="AttComp" onfocusout="getBV()">
<span class="hiddenPR">/PR:</span><input type="text" class="myclass" id="PRReq" onfocusout="getBV()">
```

Comment: Thank you! i will try this now. What is meant with "(inputs.[i].id);"  Should i define the "id" somewhere?

Comment: You're welcome :) It's just an example to show that the elements with those ids have been selected. You are able to access the current element using `input[i]`. With that you can perform any useful action you may need.

Answer (score 1):

CSS selectors are powerful enough for your need on their own. You can use a substring matching attribute selectors, a "starts with" syntax inspired by regexes : `div[id^=AttVector]`

Reads "Nodes of type div with an attribute id starting with "AttVector"

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^=AttVector]");
console.log(Array.from(elements));
```

```html
<div id="AttVector1"/>
<div id="AttVector2"/>
<div id="AttVector3"/>
<div id="AttVector4"/>
```

Comment: But i need to predefine <"AttVector1", "AttVector2">, right? Is there any chance without predefining and just being "responsive"? 

Im actually having the problem, that if i get more then two "AttVector" back, my Code cant assign the second "AttVector" therefore only the first calculation works.

Comment: What do you mean by "assign the second AttVector"

Comment: Basically, this Code should calculate with the Input the user made. But i've made the mistake, that i only have the id "AttVector" - if the user expands the calculator, and wants to calculate two things simultaneously the code cant assign the second calculation and it stays empty. 

Hopefully i could express my problem good enough - sorry for my bad english :D

Comment: @MKaya9277 It looks like you've introduced an XY problem in the question. I think you should ask a __new question__ (do not edit this question) about the dynamically created elements, include _all_ the relevant code, and explain in details what you want your code to do, and what it does instead.